# Committing files/folder into second repository when within first?

Tags: svn, repository, directory-structure

i have a repostiroy structure "1" which is like:

```
/a
/a/b
```

in /a/b i need to store files which willgo into repository "2", ideallyin the same folder structure /a/b as well.

how do i dothis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Svn Externals maybe whereby /a/b will be in one repo and is an external to that /a/b in another

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html